# How to call javascript function in callback function of codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want call the javascript function into callback function of codeigniter controller.

Controller: Callback function

```
public function email_exist($id) {
        $this->db->where('email', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, $this->email_validate());          
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
```

Javascript: Alert function

```
function email_validate(){
    alert('Invalid Email Id');
}
```

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Login::email_validate()

Filename: C:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniterProject1\application\controllers\login.php

Line Number: 46

login_form.php

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
<form name="form">
    <div class="loginform">
        <?php echo form_label('LOGIN', 'login'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <?php echo form_input('email', 'E-MAIL', set_value('email')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
        <?php echo form_password('password', 'PASSWORD', set_value('password')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class='checkbox'>
        <?php
        echo form_checkbox(array(
            'name' => 'remember',
            'id' => 'remember',
            'value' => 'REMEMBER ME',
            'checked' => FALSE,
            'style' => 'margin:1px'
        )) . form_label('REMEMBER ME', 'remember');
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class='btnlogin'>
        <?php echo form_submit('login', 'LOGIN'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't do that. There are a lot of libraries in `php` for email validation.

Comment: Actually css is not working, that's why I am trying with js

Comment: If you want to modify the css to the field when the email is invalid do only a frontend validation. No need to bother with the controller.

Comment: ok, But I don't know how to do?. Let me try. I don't know how to give css for validation_errors

Comment: Make two css classes: `error` and `valid` and from js with jQuery: `$(this).RemoveClass('valid').AddClass('error')`

Comment: You can also add animation with animate o trasition from css 3

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that in Codeigniter, use Codeigniter default form validation library

[View here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial)

if you want to add css for validation errors then try **set_error_delimeters()**

if you have bootstrap then use

> alert alert-danger

class, else create one class

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
```

[see](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters)

**[other suggestions]**

instead of putting all error in the top, you can also try

```
<?php 
echo form_error('email');
form_input('email', 'E-MAIL', set_value('email'));
 ?>
```

other options is jquery validation or js validation, write js in view or external .js file

```
<?php
    data = array(
            'name'          => 'username',
            'id'            => 'username', //use the id for jquery validation $('#username').on('blur', function() { });
            'value'         => 'johndoe',
            'maxlength'     => '100',
            'size'          => '50',
            'style'         => 'width:50%'
            'onBlur' => 'email_validate();' //use this for javascript validation
    );

    echo form_input($data);
?>
```

*im unable to comment, thats why posting as answer*

Comment: Thanks but I have done something like this:  <div class="email">
        <?php echo form_input('email', 'E-MAIL', set_value('email')); ?><br>
        <div id="validation_errors">
            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
        </div>
    </div> and CSS style  #validation_errors{
    color: red;
}

Comment: <div id="validation_errors"> makes lots on code in our view , just add  
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="validation_errors">', '</div>'); in controller (at validation check)